# deep copy of objects containing unordered_map of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, copy, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, deep-copy

I have the following situation:

I need to create a deep (!) copy of a variable from type `A`. This variable contains a vector of type `B`. Class `B` is not copyable, because it contains a `std::unordered_map` whos value is a `unique_ptr` (which is not copyable). I would like to avoid making  `B` copyable via a copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

One problem is that the type of the `unique_ptr` is just the base type. The actual objects are derived from `C` and contain different members and have different constructors.

```
class A{
public:
    A(const A&);            // how should I implement this?
    A& operator=(const A&); // how should I implement this?
private:
    vector<B> vectorOfB;
}

class B{
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<C> mapOfDerivedTypesOfC;
}

class C{}

class C_1: public C{
public:
    C_1(double x)
}

class C_2: public C{    
public:
    C_2(double y, double z)
}
```

Background:
The purpose of class A is to read a lot of large text files with data and create many objects. 
Afterwards I have to run monte-carlo simulations with this objects. For every simulation I need a fresh copy of A. 
I do not want to read in all the text files every time because it is time consuming. Therefore it is necessary to make a deep copy of A. During one simulation I want to avoid copying B because it makes no sence that this object should ever be copied. I think using a sharded_ptr does not help because I need a deep copy and the simulations run in parallel using openMP.

Edit:
I think the overall question is how should I copy the unordered_map

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: `B` needs to be copied but you want to not have a copy operation on it. How does that make sense?

Comment: The idea is that during one simulation `B` should never be copied. I only need to copy `A` for every monte carlo simulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the technique is known as "virtual copy constructor":

```
// in baseclass
public:
unique_ptr<Base> clone() const
{
    unique_ptr<Base> other(this->do_clone());
    assert(typeid(*this) == typeid(*other));
    return other;
}
private:
virtual Base* do_clone() const = 0;

// in derived class
private:
virtual Derived* do_clone() const
{
    return new Derived(*this);
}
```

The idea is that a type eventually has info how to clone instances of itself, so you delegate cloning to it via a virtual function. The assertion makes sure that the derived class correctly implements/overrides the baseclass implementation.

Comment: What is the `assert` supposed to do?

Comment: See last sentence: "The assertion makes sure that the derived class correctly implements/overrides the baseclass implementation."

Comment: I tried to implement it with your approach, thank you very much for the imput. One question: should do_clone be virtual? or what does `=0` do for a non virtual function?

Comment: Yes, should be virtual.

Comment: @user7431005 • the pattern is called the non-virtual interface pattern (NVI).  Overkill for small projects, but extremely useful for larger projects.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern

Comment: answer accepted! Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: But pure virtual made sure of this, did it not? Unless you mean it is supposed to catch a derived class slicing itself.

Comment: You can derive from derived classes again, @PasserBy, and then you must override `do_clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you would need to write a virtual function in `C` for each inheriting class to override. Something like

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<C> anotherOnePlease() = 0;
```

Then you can use this function on each `C *`, and create a new map. Kind of sucks, but at least you can write a somewhat simple function for copying the map if you implement this function for each derived `C`.

Comment: If I do so my return type from `C_1` would need to be `C_1` not `C`. Is this possible?

Comment: You can cast a `C_1 *` to a `C *` since it's a pointer to the base class. This is fine as long as `C_1` is derived from `C`. Note that this is only true for pointers, not values. This is the same reason you can store them in the map together.

Comment: Of course you also should use `std::unqiue_ptr<C>` too instead of `C *` here, I'm just writing it like that since it's shorter.

Comment: ok, I think I understand your approach. I will try to implement it like this.